# Cross-platform help viewer with search functionality

Tags: python, documentation, cross-platform, chm

I am looking for a help viewer like Windows CHM that basically provides support for

1. adding content in HTML format
2. define Table of Contents
3. decent search

It should work on Windows, Mac and Linux. Bonus points for also having support for generating a "plain HTML/javascript" version that can be viewed in any browser (albeit without search support).

Language preference: Python

Answer (score 2):

[wxHtmlHelpController](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxhtmlhelpcontroller.html#wxhtmlhelpcontroller), which is part of [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/), is a cross-platform viewer for HtmlHelp.

I'm not sure how easy it is to use it from a non-wxWidgets program, but I think it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

wxHtmlHelpController doesn't support any scripting within pages, nor does it support css.